# init.d / rc2.d script gets executed twice sometimes

Tags: boot, scripts, init.d

I have a startup script, that *sometimes* gets executed twice (a few seconds apart) upon system boot (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS). Sometimes it only gets executed once! The script is located at `/etc/init.d/TEST` and I have a symlink `/etc/rc2.d/S99TEST` which points to the script.

The problem is that, upon system boot, the script is *sometimes* executed twice, with a pause of a few seconds in between. How can I debug this? I don't see mention of the script name in any of the system logs (/var/log/*). I am at a loss.

Here is the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          test_boot
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: test_boot
# Description:       test_boot app
### END INIT INFO

exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>>/home/username/TEST.log 2>&1

echo "---"
echo "---"
echo "Starting: $(date)"
sleep 2
echo "User: $(whoami)"
echo "Caller: $(ps -o args= $PPID)"
sleep 2
echo "Done: $(date)"
```

Here is the TEST.log file after a clean boot:

```
---
---
Starting: Mon Feb 12 21:26:35 UTC 2018
User: root
Caller: /sbin/init tegra_keep_boot_clocks
Done: Mon Feb 12 21:26:39 UTC 2018
---
---
Starting: Mon Feb 12 21:26:59 UTC 2018
User: root
Caller: /sbin/init tegra_keep_boot_clocks
Done: Mon Feb 12 21:27:03 UTC 2018
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script isn't checking inputs, like the action passed in. Look at the documentation in `/etc/init.d/README`, `/etc/init.d/skeleton`, and some of the other scripts like `/etc/init.d/kmod` to evaluate what action is being passed to the script on execution (in `$1`) and take the appropriate response to the action.